# Simple decimal values sum calculation problem

Tags: c#-3.0, sum

I have a project where i get some values over some entities and summing into a property of another entity.

Now if say sum (5,00 + 100,01 + 16.236 + 252,03) = 373,27 based on windows 7 calculator and based on simple mathematics.

But when this happens with C# code

entity.SumValue += someEntity1.Value....
entity.SumValue += someEntity2.Value....

SumValue = 373,26

I (but not in all cases) lose a cent (for euros) :P

Any idea to get what i need?

Comment: why do you add using `+=` operator ... ?

Comment: The problem is rounding error, but if you're already using `Decimal` there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `decimal`, it is actually impossible that C# has calculation errors. (I mean, there is always a limit in precision, but not when having such small numbers with 3 digits after comma ...)

There must be a problem somewhere else. How are the decimals created, for instance? Have they ever been turned to doubles and back, for instance when reading from the database?

Comment: I use Linq to SQL to get the objects from the database and then foreach to every entity i want to get the decimal value from it and sum it to another enity decimal property, never casting to any other type. What do you mean why using +=, I will try with sum = sum + value.

Comment: In what type are the numbers stored in the database?

Comment: The error was a result of += suming, changed into sum = sum + value and seems fine.

Comment: Still strange. There must be some rounding errors around. When you use the wrong operators, it may result in a completely different result. An error of 0.01 is weird. Rounding errors can be reduced by the order or adding, so you may still have the problem but you can't see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code the sum is equal to 373.276

```
decimal sum = 0m;
sum += 5.00m;
sum += 100.01m;
sum += 16.236m;
sum += 252.03m;
```

So what is the difference with your ?

Comment: I just use properties from entities i grab using LINQ 2 SQL.

Comment: Do your properties are decimal? And why did you wrote that (5,00 + 100,01 + 16.236 + 252,03) = 373,27 and not 373.276 ? Try to see at which step of the calculation your error occurs.